# Change variable value-- repeated IDs

Tags: r

I've this data set

```
id <- c(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
gender <- c("m","m","f","f","f","f","m","m","m","m")
x1 <-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,10,10)
x2 <- c(3,7,5,6,9,15,10,15,12,20)

alldata <- data.frame(id,gender,x1,x2)
```

which looks like:

```
id  gender  x1  x2

0   m   1   3
0   m   1   7
1   f   1   5
1   f   1   6
2   f   2   9
2   f   2   15
3   m   3   10
3   m   3   15
4   m   10  12
4   m   10  20
```

Notice that for each unique id x1 are similar, but x2 are different. I need to sort data by id and x2 (from smallest to largest)
and then for each unique id I need to set x1(for the second record) = x2 (for the first record).

The data would look like:

```
id  gender  x1  x2

0   m   1   3
0   m   3   7
1   f   1   5
1   f   5   6
2   f   2   9
2   f   9   15
3   m   3   10
3   m   10  15
4   m   10  12
4   m   12  20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this easier using `data.table`

```
> library(data.table)
> dt = data.table(alldata)
> setkey(dt, id, x2)    #sort the data
```

This next line says: within each ID for x1, take the first value of x1, then every remaining value take from x2 as needed.

```
> dt[,x1 := c(x1[1], x2)[1:.N],keyby=id] 
> dt
    id gender x1 x2
 1:  0      m  1  3
 2:  0      m  3  7
 3:  1      f  1  5
 4:  1      f  5  6
 5:  2      f  2  9
 6:  2      f  9 15
 7:  3      m  3 10
 8:  3      m 10 15
 9:  4      m 10 12
10:  4      m 12 20
```

Comment: `setorder` is the usual way to sort the data.

Comment: Another way (without having to reorder the entire data): `setDT(alldata)[order(id, x2), x1 := c(x1[1L], x2[-.N]), by=id][]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dplyr solution.

```
library(dplyr) 
arrange(alldata,id,x2) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(x1= c(first(x1), first(x2)))

Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
Groups: id

   id gender x1 x2
1   0      m  1  3
2   0      m  3  7
3   1      f  1  5
4   1      f  5  6
5   2      f  2  9
6   2      f  9 15
7   3      m  3 10
8   3      m 10 15
9   4      m 10 12
10  4      m 12 20
```

Comment: I think the `mutate` can be `mutate(x1= c(first(x1), first(x2)))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possible solution using the `seq` command to select every other record:

```
alldata <- alldata[order(id, x2),]
alldata$x1[seq(2, length(alldata$x1), 2)] <- alldata$x2[seq(1, length(alldata$x2) - 1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`rownames<-`(do.call(rbind,by(alldata,alldata$id,function(g) { o <- order(g$x2); g$x1[o[2]] <- g$x2[o[1]]; g; })),NULL);
##    id gender x1 x2
## 1   0      m  1  3
## 2   0      m  3  7
## 3   1      f  1  5
## 4   1      f  5  6
## 5   2      f  2  9
## 6   2      f  9 15
## 7   3      m  3 10
## 8   3      m 10 15
## 9   4      m 10 12
## 10  4      m 12 20
```